# An easy way to remember if a verb’s object requires accusative or dative case?

Tags: grammar, verb, grammatical-case

I am finding it difficult to find out which verb takes which case (accusative/dative). Please can somebody suggest a way to ease this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. There is no easy way as far as I know, you just have to know (or learn); sorry. ^^'

Comment: Sure: because it *is* difficult. Now, you might be more specific in your question, and that would make it answerable.

Comment: As the non-answers on the other question illustrate, there is no way to guess the case (or preposition, or other structure) associated with a verb.

Comment: To expand on that: there are often *slight* tendencies for cases to correspond with certain semantic aspects (directness, reciprocity, etc.) but they are not regular enough to be of help for learning vocabulary. The best way is always to learn verbs by learning entire sentences - paradoxically it is easier to memorize an entire utterance than a lexeme+inflection class.